# layout_centerInParent is not working after flinging a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to use another ViewHolder with the same RecyclerView, the layout that I am trying to inflate is basically RelativeLyout and ProgressBar as a child of it. The problem is that the ProgressBar has an attribute CenterInParent="True" that does not work after inflating the layout in which the Progressbar keeps being in the left of the Screen, Even though in the preView shows properly centering the screen, so the problem seems to be with inflation process as while debugging I did not see any centerInParent attribute for the inflated view.

I have tried the LinearLayout and ConstraintLayout and I even tried to set layout Parameters nothing worked. I also tried to change the parent of the inflated layout to relative layout as the actual parent is the recycler view, but also did not work.

Here is the Layout of the ViewHolder that I am trying to inflate.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Here is the Adapter

```
@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     View view;
    switch (viewType) {
        //Case List recipes
        case RECIPE_TYPE: {
            RecipeItemBinding mRecipeItemBinding = RecipeItemBinding.inflate(
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false);
            return new MyViewHolder(mRecipeItemBinding, onRecipeClickListener);
        }
        //Case Loading layout
        case LOADING_TYPE: {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.layout_loading_list_item, parent, false);
            return new LoadingViewHolder(view);
        }


 public class LoadingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public LoadingViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written the answer to hopefully help others, I just figured out what is going on, the problem was in the RecyclerView's width as it was wrap_content, it should have been match_parent.